# remove entire row in excel sheet

Tags: python

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DataBase.xlsx')
wb.active = wb['Movies']
sheet = wb.active
df = pd.read_excel('database.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Movies')

def Remove():

        Movie = input('Please Enter Movie You Want To Remove : ')
        df1 = df[df["Movie Title"].str.contains(Movie)]
        print(df1)
        
        for row in dfl:
            remove(sheet,row)
            wb.save('DataBase.xlsx')
        


Remove()
```

hi i am a total noob at this, i want to remove the entire row on the items i search for in excel from this image the entire row goes. please assist.

[image]

Comment: Next time, please provide part of your data frame so that one can reproduce your problem. I am not sure why you are using an infinite `while`-loop, but I will just take is as given. Your bug lies in the line where you query your data frame. Currently, you are selecting only rows that **satisfy** you condition. To get the desired output, you have to use the following: `df1 = df[~df["Movie_Title"].str.contains(Movie)]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('database.xlsx',sheet_name = 'Movies')

def Remove():
    while True:
        Movie = input('Please Enter Movie You Want To Remove : ')
        if Movie == 'Exit':
            break
        df = df[~df["Movie Title"].str.contains(Movie)]      
    df.to_excel('new_database.xlsx',index=False)
Remove()
```

Note: gave `Exit` input to break `while` loop
I think the above code is self-explanatory

Comment: what i am looking for is when i search my database in excel, if that item is in my list, i would like to delete the whole row in excel.

Comment: This block of code is doing exactly the same as your comment, it will look in the Movie name column and if the name is contained in the movie title it will filter data other than that row and make it available for the next iteration until you enter exit word, as soon you enter exit it save that filtered data to a new file called new_database.xlsx (not using the same name to not overwrite the file)